# Resources for topos theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topology, sites

I am trying to learn topos theory and I am finding a strong scarcity of resources. Is there any canonical textbook to refer someone to when learning this topic?

So far, I have only been able to find the following.

- The Stacks project (Part 1, Chapter 7 gives an introduction)
- "Théorie des Topos et Cohomologie Etale des Schémas" by Grothendieck, Artin and Verdier (yes, this one is quite old and in French but I have found all the necessary topics together in a better way than any other resource known to me)

In particular, I have only found a clear distinction between topology and pretopology in the second one, as well as clear guidance on how to work interchangeably between them.

Do people have any suggestions? Please list them below so other people trying to learn topos theory have a better idea of where to start!

Comment: I recommend the standard references "Sheaves in geometry and logic", by Maclane-Moerdijk, as well as the two volumes of Peter Johnstone "Sketches of an Elephant".

Comment: Googling will immediately turn up at least four more good references.

Comment: E.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos#References

Comment: Here's a small list of references (in the far from optimal form of a directory tree): [list](https://pastebin.com/raw/eaFmw2d9)

Comment: @godelian is the Elephant still in print? Are there reasonable ways to obtain a copy for less than a few hundred (or thousand) dollars?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I wouldn't know if it's still in print, but the university libraries should have it. I do know electronic copies are available online, though not legally of course.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn it's definitely available, though I think it's now a more cheaply-produced print-on-demand copy. Mine is like this, and I was unhappy to see the low-resolution of the font, the pixelation of the glyphs is visible with the naked eye in places. The binding is also not hardbound with cloth, but casewrapped. Oh, and it still costs ~$600 from OUP (I guess USD)

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of  [Topos theory reference suitable for undergraduates](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55898/topos-theory-reference-suitable-for-undergraduates/55960).  Question not exactly the same, but close enough that there’s really no difference in what answers they invite.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: The other question is about computer science (and elementary toposes), whereas this question is about Grothendieck toposes.  The answers differ accordingly.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Apart from the mention of a computer science background in the other question, I’m not sure where you’re seeing those differences in the questions.  All the question currently says is “I looked for references and all I found was the Stacks project and G–A–V”, which could be due to an interest in Grothendieck toposes but could also just be because the OP’s literature search didn’t go very far.  If the OP could give more details of their background and what aspects of topos theory they’re interested in, that would make the difference rather clearer.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: The OP used tags "sites" and "grothendieck-topology", which clearly point to Grothendieck toposes.  The other question mentioned computer science, which clearly points to elementary toposes.  Only the OP can offer clarifications, of course, but it would seem to me that the current question is already unambiguous, if not very explicit, and is certainly distinct for the other question.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Ah, my mistake — I’d missed the tags. Yes, those do make the distinction a bit clearer!

Comment: Overlaps with this question on math.stackexchange.com too - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339197/motives-and-topoi

Answer (score 20):

For a beginner, the more accessible textbooks seem to be the following two.

- Francis Borceux, [Handbook of Categorical Algebra, Volume 3](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=57956E1294F989002BCFA15186D3E772).
- Saunders Mac Lane, Ieke Moerdijk: [Sheaves in Geometry and Logic](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=4F6FC5034A0F4C25CE1CBBCA12B984EA).

They both cover sheaves, Grothendieck topologies, locales, classifying toposes,
and other classical topics.

The second book is a bit longer and covers some additional topics,
e.g., the independence of the axiom of choice and continuum hypothesis.

Answer (score 14):

Dmitri has mentioned two fantastic references, which are very complete and well written.

I will mention two short references for those that want to get the general idea, before approaching a complete book.

1. Leinster, [An informal introduction to topos theory.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.5647)
2. Borceux, [Some glances at topos theory.](https://tcsc.lakecomoschool.org/files/2018/01/Borceux.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some references on Steven Vickers works to look at topoi from other "geometric" and logical sides.

- *S. Vickers*,    [Locales and Toposes as Spaces](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Esjv/LocTopSpaces.pdf) Chapter 8 in  *M. Aiello, I. Pratt-Hartmann and J. van Benthem (eds.), Handbook of Spatial Logics, 429–496. 2007 Springer*,
- *S. Vickers*,    [Toposes pour les vraiment nuls](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Esjv/TopPLVN.pdf)
- *S. Vickers*,    [Sketches for arithmetic universes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.01559.pdf)
- *S. Vickers*,    [Arithmetic universes and classifying toposes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.04611.pdf)

I think it also worth to mention the following

- I. Moerdijk,  [Classifying Spaces and Classifying Topoi](https://www.zuj.edu.jo/download/moerdijk-classifying-spaces-and-classifying-topoi-pdf/) (surprisingly to me this one is available online as well)

For some advanced matters I also suggest to read

- T. Streicher,  [Fibered Categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.02927.pdf)

Comment: I’m not sure any of this seems relevant to a request for a “canonical textbook.”

Comment: @Kevin Arlin I agree, the refences on Vickers may be not canonical but, in my opinion good additional resources to look at topoi more widely in parallel with Johnston, Borceux, Maclane, Moerdijk and Leinster. Nonetheless Classifying Spaces and Classifying Topoi is quite canonical.